# PHP: why am I not viewing correctly the text?

Tags: php, encoding

I set up both PHP 5 and Apache to use UTF-8 encoding.
I tried to show in my browser the result of this PHP code:

```
echo "Trying to visualize the letter ü"
```

and it shows me this result:

```
Trying to visualize the letter �
```

Why?

Comment: Is your file in UTF-8 (without BOM)? Is your `Content-Type` also UTF-8 ?

Comment: Probably have to show where you made configuration changes. Seems to me like you just haven't set it up correctly

Comment: @Glavić How can I see that? Anyway, I wrote it with notepad (win 8)

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I added in the php conf file "default_charset = "utf-8";" and in the apache conf file "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8"

Comment: Try this `<?php header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); echo "Trying to visualize the letter ü";`

Comment: And I don't know how to change character in file with notepad, but with notepad++ it is fairly simple, just go on `Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`.

Comment: @Glavić nothing, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Glavić Is there any way to do that in Linux?

Comment: Try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311750/change-file-encoding-to-utf-8-via-vim-in-a-script or with iconv = `iconv -f source-encoding -t target-encoding <infile >outfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo "Trying to visualize the letter ü";
```

If this doesn't work, than your file is in different encoding that utf-8.

[What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

[Change File Encoding to utf-8 via vim in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311750/change-file-encoding-to-utf-8-via-vim-in-a-script)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved by saving the file in UTF-8 (default was ANSI). I did "File->Save as..->Encoding: UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your documents "Content-Type" http header, and set the charset to the encoding that you're using:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```