# how to change log4cplus log file to utf8

Tags: logging, utf-8, log4cplus

I have been handed a code which uses log4cplus as the logger application. How can I generate a UTF8 logging file for it?. The logfile being created by log4cplus is in ASCII format at the moment.

I have tried the follow

Setting the file encoding of the log file by following instructions at [Change File Encoding to utf-8 via vim in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311750/change-file-encoding-to-utf-8-via-vim-in-a-script)

```
vi dataLog.txt
:set bomb
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:wq
```

I have also tried changing the .properties file

```
log4cplus.logger.dl=TRACE,DATA

log4cplus.appender.DATA=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.DATA.Locale=en-US
log4cplus.appender.DATA.File=/usr/vm/log/data/dataLog.txt
log4cplus.appender.DATA.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4cplus.appender.DATA.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4cplus.appender.DATA.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.DATA.layout.ConversionPattern=%D{%d/%b/%y %H:%M:%S.%q} %-9c %-5p %m%n
```

I am not sure on the exact version of log4cplus however a locate resulted in the following

```
/usr/lib/liblog4cplus-1.0.so.4
/usr/lib/liblog4cplus-1.0.so.4.0.0
/usr/lib/liblog4cplus-1.0.so.4.0.0_load
/usr/lib/liblog4cplus.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Since log4cplus 1.1.0-RC10 you can specify locale to be imbued into `std::filestream` used by file appenders. See [FileAppender documentation](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1FileAppender.html), especially the `Locale` property. In your case, try to imbue it with `en_US.UTF-8`.